# having problem inserting date in mysql database

Tags: mysql

After inserting date in table, the date is being displayed as 0000-00-00

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/$id?api_key=c1259239b41c48480d727f85c677fbf6");

$moviedetailsArray = json_decode($content,true);

$budget = $moviedetailsArray['budget'];
$rlsdate = $moviedetailsArray['release_date'];

$query = "UPDATE `latestmoviesdetails` SET `budget` = $budget,`releasedate` = $rlsdate WHERE movieid = $id";

mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the date, what date ends up as 0000-00-00? You should btw add NO_ZERO_DATE to @@sql_mode to prevent 0000-00-00 in table

Comment: Also, [How to prevent sql injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Just because its from an API doesn't mean its trusted.

Comment: What did your incoming date look like?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the query is that the date value is not quoted.
Use the following:

```
$query = "UPDATE `latestmoviesdetails` SET `budget` = $budget,`releasedate` = '$rlsdate' WHERE movieid = $id";
```

Notice that the change here is only adding single quotes around the date value (the `$rlsdate`).

In other words: `... set date_field=2019-03-19` will fail, while `... set date_field='2019-03-13'` would work

Answer (score 0):

Is this Perl code?

I think the problem is that SQL doesn't recognize the date format. Just before doing the query, insert a print statement to see what exactly is in `$rlsdate`.

MySQL expects date in this format: `'2019-03-13 16:35:42'`

If your date is in unix timestamp format, you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in your query:

```
$query = "UPDATE `latestmoviesdetails` SET `budget` = $budget,
                 `releasedate` = FROM_UNIXTIME($rlsdate)
          WHERE movieid = $id";
```

If it's in a date format that is not `YYYY-MM-DD`, use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function. Example:

```
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y');
        -> '2013-05-01'
mysql> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
        -> '2004-04-31'
```

Comment: This is PHP code